# Kafka stream join with a specific key as input

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-join

I have 3 different topics with 3 Avro files in schema registry, I want to stream these topics and join them together and write them into one topic. the problem is the key I want to join is different with the key I write the data into each topic.

Let's say we have these 3 Avro files:
***Alarm***:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Alarm",
  "namespace" : "com.kafkastream.schema.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "alarm_id",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Unique identifier of the alarm."
  }, {
    "name" : "ne_id",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Unique identifier of the  network element ID that produces the alarm."
  }, {
    "name" : "start_time",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "is the timestamp when the alarm was generated."
  }, {
    "name" : "severity",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "doc" : "The severity field is the default severity associated to the alarm ",
    "default" : null
  }]
}
```

**Incident:**

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Incident",
  "namespace" : "com.kafkastream.schema.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "incident_id",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Unique identifier of the incident."
  }, {
    "name" : "incident_type",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "doc" : "Categorization of the incident e.g. Network fault, network at risk, customer impact, etc",
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "alarm_source_id",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Respective Alarm"
  }, {
    "name" : "start_time",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "is the timestamp when the incident was generated on the node."
  }, {
    "name" : "ne_id",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "ID of specific network element."
  }]
}
```

***Maintenance:***

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Maintenance",
  "namespace" : "com.kafkastream.schema.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "maintenance_id",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "The message number is the unique ID for every maintenance"
  }, {
    "name" : "ne_id",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "The NE ID is the network element ID on which the maintenance is done."
  }, {
    "name" : "start_time",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "The timestamp when the maintenance start."
  }, {
    "name" : "end_time",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "The timestamp when the maintenance start."
  }]
}
```

I have 3 topics in my Kafka for each of these Avro (ley's say alarm_raw, incident_raw, maintenance_raw) and whenever I wanted to write into these topics I am using ne_id as a key (so the topic partitioned by ne_id). now I want to join these 3 topics and get a new record and write it into a new topic. The problem is I want to join ***Alarm*** and ***Incident*** based on **alarm_id** and **alarm_source_id** and join alarm and maintenance based on **ne_id**. I want to avoid creating a new topic and re-assign a new key. Is there anyway that I specify the key while I am joining?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends what kind of join you want to use (c.f. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics)

For **KStream-KStream** join, there is currently (`v0.10.2` and earlier) no other way than setting a new key (e.g., by using `selectKey()`) and do a repartitioning.

For **KStream-KTable** join, Kafka `0.10.2` (will be released in the next weeks) contains a new feature called `GlobalKTables` (c.f. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-99%3A+Add+Global+Tables+to+Kafka+Streams). This allows you to do a non-key join on the KTable (i.e., a *KStream-GlobalKTable* join and thus you do not need to repartition the data in you GlobalKTable).

> Note: a KStream-GlobalKTable join has different semantics than a KStream-KTable join. It is not time synchronized in contrast to the later, and thus, the join is non-deterministic by design with regard to GlobalKTable updates; i.e., there is no guarantee what KStream record will be the first to "see" a GlobalKTable updates and thus join with the updated GlobalKTable record.

There are plans to add a **KTable-GlobalKTable** join, too. This might become available in `0.10.3`. There are no plans to add "global" KStream-KStream joins though.

Comment: My case is KStream-KStream so there is no way other than re-partition my topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the same key by modifying it.
You can use `KeyValueMapper` through which you can modify your key as well as value.
You should use it as follows:

```
val modifiedStream = kStream.map[String,String](
    new KeyValueMapper[String, String,KeyValue[String,String]]{
        override def apply(key: String, value: String): KeyValue[String, String] = new KeyValue("modifiedKey", value)
    }
)
```

You can apply above logic on multiple `Kstream` objects to maintain a single key for joining `KStream`s.